# How to integrate BRLMPrinterKit with iOS for a Flutter App?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart, printing

I have been trying to integrate the Brother's SDK for printing with the iOS part of my Flutter project.

The following are the steps that I followed :

- I added the BRLMPrinterKit.framework & BRLMPrinterKitW.framework to the Framework folder in my Xcode project.
- Added $(PROJECT_DIR)/Frameworks to the Framework Search Paths and Header Search Paths.
- I then added #import <BRLMPrinterKit/BRLMPrinterKit.h> to the Runner-Bridging-Header.h.

After performing the above steps, when I try to import BRLMPrinterKit in the appdelegate file, I am getting a "No such module BRLMPrinterKit" error.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add "import BRLMPrinterKit" in your Swift file. So, just delete this line and you should be OK.

Adding `#import <BRLMPrinterKit/BRLMPrinterKit.h>` as you did to the Bridging Header is sufficient to be able to use SDK APIs in a Swift file.

A few other tips:

1. Do **NOT** include both frameworks in your project.

- Use BRLMPrinterKitW.framework if you are ONLY supporting WIFI
- Use BRLMPrinterKit.framework if you are supporting Bluetooth (and also WIFI)

2. You must "embed and sign" the framework via the General tab for the target. Otherwise your app will crash as soon as you run it.
3. You may need to add `#import <BRLMPrinterKit/BRPtouchPrinterKit.h>` to your Bridging Header too, if you need to access any APIs from the older v3 SDK (BRPtouchPrinterKit) that do not have equivalent APIs yet in the v4 SDK (BRLMPrinterKit).

Comment: Thankyou for taking your time out to answer the question, I really appreciate it. I actually didn't use the BRLMPrinterKit instead I used the Airprint option in iOS, it was much easier to implement and it supports a wide range of printers. :)

Comment: Would you be so kind as to accept (or at least upvote) my answer? Glad you were able to use AirPrint successfully!! Of course, AirPrint does not allow printing by Bluetooth to any of Brother's MFi printers. So, you may will still want to use the SDK in the future. You are welcome to reach out directly to Brother Technical Support as well and we are happy to help. https://developerprogram.brother-usa.com/

Comment: I'm getting **could not build module 'BRLMPrinterKit'** @robr2112

Comment: @iSrinivasan27, in response to what? And what have you done to try to resolve it? Which SDK version? Which Printer Model? Please reach out via the developer program website provided in comment above.

Comment: @robr2112, is it the developer program only for developer located in USA, since it only allow USA address when sign up :(, thanks.

Comment: @iSrinivasan27: The developer program mentioned is for US-based developers only, with some exceptions. You can try sending an email to sdksupport@brother.com, and they can try to route your inquiry to the proper location after you answer some questions.

Comment: @Will, see previous comment. SO won't let me tag both of you.